# Java + TestNG. Not present element fail to go else statement

Tags: java, testng

```
    boolean a = browser1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input")).isDisplayed();

    if (a == true)
    {
        extent.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Website launched");
    }
    else
    {
        extent.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Website no launched");
    }
```

If the xpath element is present it is successful to log the true statement. But for not present xpath element it will not go into else statement. How can I set to find/verify the exist or non exist element in testng?

Comment: so, basically, a is always true?

Comment: or did you configure your logger only to log the status PASS ?

Comment: Only the element is valid, it will be true. If I put an invalid element xpath. It will just stop and will not go into the if else.

Comment: did you debug to verify this?

Comment: Yes, I try the debug but Im unable to find the cause. and not the logger issue. Because i try this when the xpath element is invalid it will not go into the else statement as well.

Comment: Do you mean to say -- you want to set Pass / Fail result in testNG results ??

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();
  browser.get("http://www.google.com");
  
  boolean a = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[")).isDisplayed();
  
  if (a == true)
  {
   System.out.println("Yes");
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("No");
  }

 }

}

Comment: Yes, I would like to set Pass / Fail result in TestNG

Comment: is an Exception thrown somewhere?

Comment: No. not using exception thrown..

Comment: hate it to tell you, but this makes no sense. either the boolean is true, or it is false. Either the if-block, or the else-block will be executed.

Comment: WebElement a = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]"));
  
  if (a.isDisplayed())
  {
   System.out.println("Yes");
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("No");
  }

Comment: If i am not using the boolean, if the element is not displayed, it will not go the else...

Comment: ... a.isDisplayed() is a boolean

Answer (score 0):

Using Assert will send Pass/Fail result in testNG.

```
WebDriver browser1 = new FirefoxDriver();
        try
        {
            WebElement w = browser1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input"));
            boolean flag = w.isDisplayed();

            if(flag)
            {
                Assert.assertTrue(true, "Website Launched");
            }
            else
            {
                Assert.fail("Website no launched");
            }

        }catch(NoSuchElementException n)
        {
            Assert.fail("Website no launched");
        }
```

Comment: Thought something similar, but since the OP states there is no Exception thrown ..

Comment: Pardon me, what you mean by OP states ?

Comment: "OP states" means the same as: "the Original Poster said"

Answer (score 0):

Create function like below code to find element:

```
boolean a = isElementPresent(By.xpath("//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input"));

public boolean isElementPresent(String element){
    try{
        browser1.findElement(By.xpath(element)).isDisplayed();
        return true;
       }
       catch(Exception ex){
           return false;
       }

}
```